# Unity - Wrong positioning of game objects after instantiating them

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, gameobject

I instantiate a Board GameObject using this code:

```
mainBoard.transform.position = camera.ViewportToWorldPoint(new Vector3(0f, 0f, camera.nearClipPlane));
```

Then I try to fill this board by instantiating Tiles GameObjects with loop:

```
for (int x = 0; x < width; x++)
         {
             for (int y = 0; y < height; y++)
             {                
                 Vector3 tempPosition = camera.ViewportToWorldPoint(new Vector3(x, y, camera.nearClipPlane));                    
                 GameObject backgroundTile = Instantiate(tilePrefab, tempPosition, Quaternion.identity) as GameObject;
                 backgroundTile.transform.SetParent(this.transform);
                 backgroundTile.name = "( " + x + "," + y + ")";

                 allTiles[x, y] = backgroundTile;               
             }
         }
```

But the tiles are placed on wrong place. They should be placed one next to each other at the bottom left of the screen but only the first Tile is at correct position.

How can I get all tiles correctly placed on the board?

**EDIT**
Here is the prefab I am instantiating:
[image]

This is what I get:

[image]

and this is what I am trying to get:

[image]

Thank you.

Comment: its position will be offset by anything you did in the prefab

Comment: @BugFinder I added a screenshot of my prefab.

Comment: What exactly turns out to be wrong with the position of the others

Comment: @BugFinder I added more screenshots showing the result I get and what I am trying to do.

Comment: So it looks like as simple as your blocks you're putting down arent 1 unit wide, therefore when you put them down 1 unit apart.... thats what you get.. So, you need to use the size of your blocks to multiply where to put them.

Answer (score 0):

I did not fully look at your code but try this;

```
for (int x = 0; x < width; x++)
         {
             for (int y = 0; y < height; y++)
             {                
                 Vector3 tempPosition = camera.ViewportToWorldPoint(new Vector3(x, y, camera.nearClipPlane));                    
                 GameObject backgroundTile = Instantiate(tilePrefab, tempPosition, Quaternion.identity,this.transform) as GameObject;

                 backgroundTile.name = "( " + x + "," + y + ")";

                 allTiles[x, y] = backgroundTile;               
             }
         }
```

give it a try, sometimes UI makes stupid things if you set parent after you instantiate. So it is better to setparent when you instantiate like this;

```
GameObject backgroundTile = Instantiate(tilePrefab, tempPosition, Quaternion.identity,this.transform) as GameObject;
```

Comment: I tried your suggestions but didn't make any difference.

Answer (score 0):

If it is for building UI element, I would use the grid component or the vertical/horizontal  layout depending on what you want to do. Just set the instantiated element to the grid parent that will take care of the layout